# An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file …LoginDB.mdf failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

```
string _connStr = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C: \Users\James JJ\Desktop\jj\Web App\Website\App_Data\LoginDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
string _query = "INSERT INTO [RegistrationTable] (Email, Password, HomeAddress, PostalCode, Gender) VALUES (@email, @password, @haddress, @postalcode, @gender)";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr))
{
    using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())
    {
        comm.Connection = conn;
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        comm.CommandText = _query;

        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", Emailtxt.Text);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", Passwordtxt.Text);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@homeaddress", hAddresstxt.Text);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postalcode", Postaltxt.Text);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", gender);

        conn.Open();
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Response.Redirect("RegistrationSuccess.aspx");
    }
}
```

I really tried all the solutions on the net but I still keep getting errors.

Comment: what is it the exception you are getting?

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...